# Can't run Tomcat Server on VS code

Tags: java, tomcat, visual-studio-code

I can't run Tomcat server on VS code.

The error message says below

```
[apache-tomcat-9.0.37]: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

However my tomcat folder is put on D drive, same folder as source code.
I don't know why it's trying to search "C:\Program" folder.
I really appreciate it if you could help.
Thank you

jdk1.8
Windows10
VS code1.47.2
Tomcat9.0.37

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1qCA.png)

Comment: Have you checked this documentation? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tomcat-jetty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this is broken in latest build of Plug In . I faced similar issue .Now I am reverting back to a plug in version which is 2 months old . This seems to work.
I was surprised that VS.Code automatically upgrades the plug in.

Comment: Thank you so much, you advice is correct. Initially the plugin, Tomcat for Java version was v0.11.3 but I tried installing v0.11.2 and it works.

Comment: Confirmed!  0.11.3 breaks when there are spaces in the path to tomcat.  0.11.2 works!  Thanks Nikhil!

Comment: Probably a silly question but, how could you install an earlier version in VS code?

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me crazy! I just downgraded from 0.11.3 to 0.11.2 and that cleared it right up. In VSCode, look at the extension and hit the down arrow in the Uninstall button - then pick "install another version" to switch

Answer (score 4):

On my side, I found that this extension looks your "java.home" path specified in your settings.json before it start, so commenting out the path and the error shall be solved.

Answer (score 2):

I got this today and I 'fixed' it with

```
C:\\Progra~1\\AdoptOpenJDK\\jdk-11.0.7.10-hotspot\\
```

With `Progra~1` I just omitted the whitespace, which was enough to get things running.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue while setting up VS Code for a dynamic web app and I found that we can solve this issue by removing `Java.home` variable from VS Code `settings.json`. you can find it by **ctrl+shift+p** and search for `settings.json`. After you remove `Java.home` variable, VS Code will search for default `JAVA_HOME` variable from environment variables and it runs Tomcat server. [settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQBNa.png)

I have removed JAVA_HOME from settings and it's working for me [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNjPe.png).

Answer (score -2):

1. install Java extenstion pack
2. In `setting.json`

   ```
   "java.home" : "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_261"

    change to "java.home" : "C:\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_261"
   ```