# demo.war file won't run on Tomcat sever

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, visual-studio-code

I've created a Maven webapp project on Visual Studio code. Whenever I try to run the war file I get this message

"@Error: Command failed with exit code 1"

and the output says

"[apache-tomcat-10.0.6]: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

I know the problem is with Tomcat but I don't know how to get to that specific error.

Comment: Have you tried unzipping the WAR to examine its contents?

Comment: Do you mean demo.war? It's not zipped. Also when I open it from File Explorer it just opens the file up in Visual Studio

Comment: A [WAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)) file is a zipped folder of stuff, mainly config files and [JAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) files. Each JAR in turn is also a zipped folder. Use any zipping tool to unpack them. You can likely look at a `target` folder in your IDE, where all the files and JARs are placed before zipping into a WAR.

Comment: Can you post the error screenshot? Please follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63910054/visual-studio-code-setup-for-java-webapp-project-without-main-method/63930087#63930087) and try again.

Comment: Has your question been solved?

Comment: No. I decided to take a break and switch to a javascript project. But I'm having trouble there too..

Comment: @Bl1xvan. Have you ever tried the link i post before? About Untracked files, you can add `"java.configuration.checkProjectSettingsExclusions": true` in **User Settings.json** to hide them.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using older version of Tomcat plugin as it was mentioned here:
[Can't run Tomcat Server on VS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63013587/cant-run-tomcat-server-on-vs-code)

Comment: No dice. 

And since I've changed the java.home path, my war file won't run on any of my servers at all. It says that the files are "Untracked". Does this mean anything? I've never noticed that before.